# gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3> Bad Gateway - error 504

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, gunicorn, ubuntu-20.04

I am getting this error from my django application running on ubuntu version 20.04.
I have tried all the solution I have seen online, including here on StackOverflow but none of them seems to have solved problem.

Here is the error:

```
[2021-09-27 21:32:14 +0000] [607] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 607)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]: [2021-09-27 21:32:14 +0000] [608] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     worker.init_process()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_proce>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     self.load_wsgi()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     self.callable = self.load()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/unisell/unisell/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_applica>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     self._setup(name)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/unisell/unisell/settings/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     from .production import *
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/unisell/unisell/settings/production.py", line 13, in <module>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG'] == 'True'
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]:     raise KeyError(key) from None
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]: KeyError: 'DEBUG'
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[608]: [2021-09-27 21:32:14 +0000] [608] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 608)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]: [2021-09-27 21:32:14 +0000] [609] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     worker.init_process()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_proce>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     self.load_wsgi()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     self.callable = self.load()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/unisell/unisell/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_applica>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     self._setup(name)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/unisell/unisell/settings/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     from .production import *
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/unisell/unisell/settings/production.py", line 13, in <module>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG'] == 'True'
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]:     raise KeyError(key) from None
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]: KeyError: 'DEBUG'
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[609]: [2021-09-27 21:32:14 +0000] [609] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 609)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]: [2021-09-27 21:32:14 +0000] [605] [WARNING] Worker with pid 609 was terminated due to signal 15
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     self.sleep()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     self.reap_workers()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     sys.exit(run())
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     super().run()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     Arbiter(self).run()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     self.stop()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     time.sleep(0.1)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     self.reap_workers()
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:   File "/root/projects/varsell/varsell/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com gunicorn[605]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 27 21:32:14 server.varsell.com systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
```

Please I need help on this. **All the required environment variables are all set**, I can't seem to point out what the problem is. It keeps raising same error.

When I print my environment variables, this is what I get:

```
root@server:~# printenv DEBUG
False
```

Please help!

Comment: What gunicorn command are you running?

Comment: ```/root/projects/varsell/varsell/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          unisell.wsgi:application ``` I am using a systemd service to run the gunicorn command